# Can I transfer a Playstation savegame to someone?

Tags: ps3

I own a Playstation 3 that I use with my girlfriend and her sister.
My girlfriend's sister played "Tekken Tag Tournament 2" on her sister account until she got her own Playstation. Now, she would like to get back her savegame on her Playstation.

The problem is that the savegame is copy-locked, I can't export it on a flash drive. The only thing I can do is uploading on the cloud with PS Plus.

So, I was wondering : Is a Playstation Plus tied to one user account ? Or can my girlfriend suscribe to PS+, upload the Tekken savegame on the cloud and then let her sister connect with her own user account on her new playstation and get back the save from her sister's PS+ account  ?

Thanks !

Comment: A forum post [here](http://www.ps3hax.net/showthread.php?t=47711) details multiple methods of reassigning your save file to a different account.

Answer (score 1):

One Playstation Plus account can be used in up to two different consoles.

To be more precise, one Playstation Network account can be used in up to two consoles (it used to be five) at the same time. That's where the restriction is. You can add/remove devices from an account though...

So yeah, I believe they could share that PS+ account on both consoles and use the same saved game.

Comment: Note that the save file is probably locked to the account so that if the girlfriend's sister wants trophies on her account or to play online using her own account she'll be better off just starting over unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, they should check that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this myself, it depends on the game. Some games let you export it and some don't, backing up to psn cloud will work, the main problem being is that it detects the user in the save. So if the system you give it to does not use the same username (psn account) then they will not let you play that gamesave sometimes and it will disable trophies, if that matters to you.